# how to use google map api in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, google-maps

I am developing windows phone application 8.1 and need to know that how to add google maps API in c# environment?"

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps doesn't have a .NET map control that can be used in Windows Phone 8.1.